# update polygon with values of points postgres/postgis

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have polygons and points. Now I want to merge one specific attribute column of the points if they intersects with a polygon and add this in a new column to the "parent" polygon.

The following query already works:

```
select polygons.id, (concat(string_agg(points.desc, '; '))) AS sum 
from polygons
left join points
on ST_Intersects(polygons.geom, points.geom)
group by polygons.id;
```

But how to update the polygons?

This works not:

```
update polygons set description = foo 
from (
select polygons.id, (concat(string_agg(points.desc, '; ')))
from polygons
left join points
on ST_Intersects(polygons.geom, points.geom)
group by polygons.id) as foo;
```

Hopefully you have a few tips...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for the simple question. Thats how it works:

```
update polygons 
set description = select(concat(string_agg(points.desc, '; '))) 
       from points
       where ST_Intersects(points.geom, polygons.geom));
```

Problem solved...